# JSON Serializing Mongo Collection Object for use with Celery

Tags: python, pymongo

What I am trying to do is to perform some operations on a `pymongo` `Cursor` object and a `pymongo` `Collection` object in a celery worker. My worker is defined as follows:

```
@app.task
def find_missing_songs(cursor_object, collection_object):
# Some operation is performed on both arguments
```

This is how I am calling the function defined above:

```
from bson.json_util import dumps
find_missing_songs.delay(dumps(cursor_object), dumps(collection_object))
```

I read that `dumps` can be useful to serialize `Cursor` objects. However, I receive the following error for `Collection` object:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'iteritems' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Is there a way through which `Collection` object can be serialized?

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize a collection object? IOW, what are you trying to do with `dumps(collection_object)`?